# Optional dependencies for PyPI packages

Tags: python, pypi

I want to create a new [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) package, but this will have an special wheels where I will invoke it like this:

```
pip install misoftware[customer1]
```

Is this possible?

If so how can I provide patches for `[customer1]`

For example my main release is:

`misoftware==1.1` and

`misoftware[customer1]`

I want

`misoftware[customer1]==1.1.2`

This will be 3 wheels total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing [`setuptools` 'extras'](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). This allows you to specify additional dependencies, so for example

- `misoftware` just installs the `misoftware` package
- `misoftware[customer1]` would install the `misoftware` package, plus some extra dependencies

The downside is that the dependencies you list in your extras must be hosted as packages themselves as well on PyPI. So you'd need to create a `misoftware_customer1` package, and so on.